# specifier-qualifier-list error in data structure

Tags: c, data-structures, valgrind

Here is some code for a data structure:

```
struct node {
    char* command;
    char** prereq;
    prereq = malloc(100*sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i<100; i++)
    {
        prereq[i]=malloc(80);
    }
    Node *next;
    char *targ;
    int isUpdated;
};
```

However, when I try to run the program with this structure in it, I'm getting this error:

```
error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘prereq’
```

After reading up on this error, it looks like it's most common when someone tries to create a linked list without declaring 'struct' inside the structure. However, I'm baffled as to how it applies to my structure.

If it helps, I have this in the header:

```
typedef struct node Node;
```

Comment: You can't write a `for` loop inside a structure definition!  Or the assignment, come to that.  Even C++ wouldn't accept it as written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write a `for` loop inside a structure definition!  Or the assignment, come to that.  Even C++ wouldn't accept it as written.

```
typedef struct node Node;
struct node
{
    char  *command;
    char **prereq;
    Node  *next;
    char  *targ;
    int    isUpdated;
};
```

That should be OK (though were it my code, I'd use `typedef struct Node Node;` and `struct Node { ... };` — structure tags are in a separate namespace from typedef names so there's no problem).

You can then put the initializer code in a separate function `initnode()` or something similar:

```
int initnode(Node *node)
{
    node->command = 0;
    node->next = 0;
    node->targ = 0;
    node->isUpdated = 0;
    if ((node->prereq = malloc(100*sizeof(char*))) == 0)
        return -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if ((node->prereq[i] = malloc(80)) == 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                 free(node->prereq[j]);
            free(node->prereq);
            node->prereq = 0;
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```